# Split C# dataset into multiple datasets

Tags: .net, dataset

I have an existing application that converts a text file to a DataSet which than gets passed to another method for processing.  Up until now, the text files have always been for 1 Location (internal client reference).

The client now has a second file format that contains multiple Locations.  I'd like to take the returned dataset from this new file and convert it to an Array of Datasets based on the Location field in the file.  This would allow us to utilize the existing method that accepts a Dataset for a single Location.

Is there a built-in method in .Net that allows me to split a DataSet into multiple datasets or would I have to create this logic myself?

Comment: You know that a `DataSet` is just a container for one or multiple `DataTable`s? So you can add another table to the `DataSet`. Apart from that you should add more context or code, otherwise it's difficult to provide more than general statements.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am aware that a DataSet contains 1 or more DataTables.  In this instance, I'm trying to take a DataSet with 1 table, and split it into multiple Datasets with 1 table.  The only reason for this approach is an existing method already uses a passed Dataset object so no more coding would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no builtin method and your requirement is pretty vague. But i'll try to give you an idea.

So you've mentioned that the location-field is the key, every unique location should get it's own `DataSet`. Then you should fill a `List<DataSet>`. You can use LINQ to read all lines from the file and group by it:

```
List<DataSet> dataSets = new List<DataSet>();
DataSet datasetSample = new DataSet();
// add table(s) with columns here
char separator = '\t';  // replace with actual separator
var locationGroups = File.ReadLines("Path")
    .Select(l => new { arr = l.Split(separator), line = l })
    .Select(x => new { x.arr, x.line, location =  x.arr[0].Trim() }) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.location);
```

Now you just need to loop the groups and fill the single `DataTable` in the `DataSet`. You can use `DataSet.Clone`, on this way you need to define the schema only once:

```
foreach (var locationgroup in locationGroups)
{ 
    DataSet ds = datasetSample.Clone(); // clones only table-schemata, no data
    DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0]; // you've mentioned that there is just one table
    foreach (var location in locationgroup)
    {
        tbl.Rows.Add(location.arr);
    }
    dataSets.Add(ds);
}
```

Note that i've  presumed that location is the first field in the line, change it accordingly.

Comment: Tim, thanks for recommending this approach as it will work perfectly.  I wasn't even aware LINQ could read from files as I've only used it with Databases.